# What to do with this

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Prove that
$$
\int^{1}_{0} \frac{\ln \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right)\right)}{x(x+1)}dx=\frac{1}{2} (\ln 2)^2-\ln \pi \ln2   
$$

I separated them 
$$
\int^{1}_{0} \frac{\ln \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right)\right)}{x}dx-\int^{1}_{0} \frac{\ln \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right)\right)}{x+1}dx
$$

For the former integral i tried to use differentiation under integration but got stuck and i have no idea about the latter one. Plz help!

Comment: Please indicate what you have tried and where you are stuck. This will allow others to better tailor their answers to your specific background and ability level. Also it will show others you are willing to learn and haven't just come here to get your homework done for you.

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about doing it so I plugged it into Wolfram and it came back that there is likely no closed form answer.

Comment: I can't paste the link properly without it breaking. You'll need to copy and paste the rest to fix this link: http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=Log%5BCos%5BPi*x%2F2%5D%5D%2F%28x+%28x+%2B+1%29%29&random=false

Comment: At least numerically everything seems to fit (up to 16 digits). But mathematica doesn't digest the exact integral

Comment: where does this problem arise, have u any sources?

Comment: @MartinNicholson [Here](https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/brilliant-integration-season-2part-2). This Tanishq is a cheater

Comment: @tanishq y did u cheat man! U spoilt the contest!

Comment: So what, I was very curious to know its solution , I couldn't wait and out of excitement I posted it here, if u are so much annoyed with it then delete the one I posted @aditya u post ur own and a small advice stop using lame words , I didn't do any criminal offence by doing this its my hunger of knowledge which forced me to do so.Also I asked just one question and everyone lose their mind , that's pretty sad.

Comment: Do you like it if you posted a question in Brilliant, and someone else asked the same question in MSE to get the answer and then posted the exact same answer? At the very least, you can cite where you get the answer.

Comment: @TanishqVarshney  ask Sudeep even I had solved that question when I was attending a lecture at school. And u could have waited for some more time as I would've posted the solution. Even I had solved it in the same way.

Comment: Firstly I don't even know when did you tell that and secondly @gohp.ihan I wouldnt feel bad, after all probability of learning something new is greater than 0.5 in my case, at the least you could do for me to remove your comment on my post. :P

Comment: You will learn something eventually, keep in mind that Sudeep (should) know the answer to that question, so you will definitely learn something without posting your question here. 

Why should I remove my comment? I'm citing where you get your answer. What you did was you plagiarize the answer provided by MartinNicholson.

And why are you so eager to post the solution? This is not a competition to see who can post the quickest. How do you feel if I kept answering problems and posting problems without giving any chance to the rest of the community?

Comment: Furthermore, you're not just being rude to the members in Brilliant, but also on MSE. You didn't bother answering the people in MSE on where you get the source of your problem. And you directly plagiarize his work onto our beloved site.

Should I go on?

Do you want me to mention the duplicate accounts you have on Brilliant that you use to upvote + share your stuff? Where's Kyle Finch?

Comment: It turns out this is an American Mathematical Monthly Problem 11152 proposed by M. Ivan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\begin{align}
&\int^{1}_{0} \frac{\ln \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right)\right)}{x}dx-\int^{1}_{0} \frac{\ln \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right)\right)}{x+1}dx=\\
&\int^{1}_{0} \frac{\ln\frac{\sin \pi x}{2\sin(\pi x/2)}}{x}dx-\int^{1}_{0} \frac{\ln \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right)\right)}{x+1}dx=\\
&\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\left(\int^{1}_{\varepsilon} \frac{\ln\frac{\sin\pi x}{2}}{x}dx-\int^{1}_{\varepsilon} \frac{\ln \left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right)\right)}{x}dx-\int^{1}_{0} \frac{\ln \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right)\right)}{x+1}dx\right)=\\
&\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\left(\int^{1}_{\varepsilon} \frac{\ln\frac{\sin\pi x}{2}}{x}dx-\int^{1}_{\varepsilon} \frac{\ln \left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right)\right)}{x}dx-\int^{2}_{1} \frac{\ln \left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right)\right)}{x}dx\right)=\\
&\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\left(\int^{1}_{\varepsilon} \frac{\ln\frac{\sin\pi x}{2}}{x}dx-\int^{2}_{\varepsilon} \frac{\ln \left(\sin \left(\frac{\pi x}{2} \right)\right)}{x}dx\right)=\\
&\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\left(\int^{1}_{\varepsilon} \frac{\ln\frac{\sin\pi x}{2}}{x}dx-\int^{1}_{\varepsilon/2} \frac{\ln \left(\sin \pi x\right)}{x}dx\right)=\\
&\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\left(-\ln 2\int^{1}_{\varepsilon}\frac{dx}{x}-\int^{\varepsilon}_{\varepsilon/2} \frac{\ln \left(\sin \pi x\right)}{x}dx \right)=\\
&\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\left(-\ln 2\int^{1}_{\varepsilon}\frac{dx}{x}-\int^{\varepsilon}_{\varepsilon/2} \frac{\ln \left(\pi x\right)}{x}dx \right)=\\
&\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\left(\ln 2\ln\varepsilon-\ln\pi\ln 2-\frac{1}{2}\left[(\ln\varepsilon)^2-(\ln\varepsilon/2)^2\right]\right)=\frac{1}{2} (\ln 2)^2-\ln \pi \ln2
\end{align}

Comment: Very clever, (+1)